# Allow Numbers and decimal in a text box using WPF at KeyDown Event

Tags: wpf

As I'm new to the WPF development.

I want to know how to handle the Numeric Text Box.

As in old Windows Development Application i can handle the above mentioned scenario
in the Key Press Event but in WPF i won't have this Event.

So i have to handle this scenario in the Key Down Event.

But it was little Complicated can i know how to handle this one.

Condition :

1. Should Allow only Numeric and a single Decimal Point.
2. Should allow only 2 characters(Numbers) after the decimal point.

Comment: Have a look at http://wpftutorial.net/DataValidation.html

Comment: PreviewKeyDown and PreviewTextInput are the event you should handle. or use a behavior. look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an extended textbox by inheriting from native TextBox. And override the OnTextInput method. Handle the input as you required. The following snippet will allow only numbers and not characters. Same way you can validate for your other needs.

```
protected override void OnTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = e.Text.ToString();
        double output = 0.0;
        bool isnumber = Double.TryParse(text, out output);
        if (!isnumber)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        base.OnTextInput(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a behavior for this stuff

```
public class TextBoxInputBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    const NumberStyles validNumberStyles = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint |
                                               NumberStyles.AllowThousands |
                                               NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign;
    public TextBoxInputBehavior()
    {
        this.InputMode = TextBoxInputMode.None;
    }

    public TextBoxInputMode InputMode { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput += AssociatedObjectPreviewTextInput;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += AssociatedObjectPreviewKeyDown;

        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(AssociatedObject, Pasting);

    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput -= AssociatedObjectPreviewTextInput;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= AssociatedObjectPreviewKeyDown;

        DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(AssociatedObject, Pasting);
    }

    private void Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        {
            var pastedText = (string)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string));

            if (!this.IsValidInput(this.GetText(pastedText)))
            {
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                e.CancelCommand();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            if (!this.IsValidInput(this.GetText(" ")))
            {
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsValidInput(this.GetText(e.Text)))
        {
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private string GetText(string input)
    {
        var txt = this.AssociatedObject;
        var realtext = txt.Text.Remove(txt.SelectionStart, txt.SelectionLength);
        var newtext = realtext.Insert(txt.CaretIndex, input);

        return newtext;
    }

    private bool IsValidInput(string input)
    {
        switch (InputMode)
        {
            case TextBoxInputMode.None:
                return true;
            case TextBoxInputMode.DigitInput:
                return CheckIsDigit(input);

            case TextBoxInputMode.DecimalInput:
                //minus einmal am anfang zulässig
                if (input.Contains("-"))
                    if (input.IndexOf("-") == 0 && input.LastIndexOf("-")==0)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                //wen mehr als ein Komma
                if (input.ToCharArray().Where(x => x == ',').Count() > 1)
                    return false;

                decimal d;
                return decimal.TryParse(input,validNumberStyles,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out d);
            default: throw new ArgumentException("Unknown TextBoxInputMode");

        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool CheckIsDigit(string wert)
    {
        return wert.ToCharArray().All(Char.IsDigit);
    }
}

public enum TextBoxInputMode
{
    None,
    DecimalInput,
    DigitInput
}
```

xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyDecimalProperty}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Behaviors:TextBoxInputBehavior InputMode="DecimalInput"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    //It's not satisfy second condition
        TextBox txtDecimal = sender as TextBox;
        if ((e.Key == Key.OemPeriod || e.Key == Key.Decimal) && (txtDecimal.Text.Contains(".") == false))
        { e.Handled = false;}
        else if ((e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9) || (e.Key == Key.Back))
        { e.Handled = false; }
        else if((e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9))
        { e.Handled = false; }
        else
        { e.Handled = true; }
```